# Unity 2d roll the dice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dice

There is a dice and there are 4 player in my game.I don't mind when I roll the dice 4 times.But When I roll the dice for the 5th time, the player doesn't move again.What can I do to get the player to move again?

```
Private IENumerator RollTheDice () 
 {
   coroutineAllowed = false ;
   int RandomDiceSide = 0;

   for (int i = 0 ; i <= 20 ; i++) 
   {
     randomDiceSide = Random. Range(0,6);
     rend. sprite = diceSides[randomDiceSide];
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0,05f);
   } 

   sıngle4gc.diceSideThrown = randomDiceSide + 1;

   if (maxPlayers > whosTurn) 
     whosTurn = 1;
     sıngle4gc.MovePlayer (whosTurn);
     whosTurn = whosTurn + 1;
     coroutineAllowed = true;
     yield return = 0;

 }
```

Comment: Did you try to [debug](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/debugging-unity-games-visual-studio) your code ?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, the code I wrote looks right, but the player doesn't move when I roll the dice for the 5th time

Comment: `yield return = 0;` doesn't look right at all

Comment: Further `Private IENumerator` are both misspelled, indicating that this is not the code you are really using

Comment: I've written all the code below as a comment, can you help me?

Comment: in this part, i think i need to change something                             
    if (maxPlayers > whosTurn) 
        whosTurn = 1;
    sıngle4gc.MovePlayer (whosTurn);
    whosTurn = whosTurn + 1;
    coroutineAllowed = true;
    yield return 0;

Comment: What happens when `whosTurn` it is exceeds the `maxPlayers`?